# Facebook API targeting sentence lines returning Chinese

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am calling the facebook targeting sentence lines with api version 2.7 and getting different results depending on the environment. In staging and development I get:

```
{
  "targetingsentencelines": [
    {
      "content": "Location - Living In:",
      "children": [
        "United States: Decatur (+10 mi) Georgia"
      ]
    },
    {
      "content": "Age:",
      "children": [
        "18 - 65+"
      ]
    },
    {
      "content": "Placements:",
      "children": [
        "News Feed on mobile devices, News Feed on desktop computers or Right column on desktop computers"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

However in preprod I get:

```
{
  "targetingsentencelines": [
    {
      "content": "Location - Living In:",
      "children": [
        "United States: Decatur (+10 mi) Georgia 喬治亞州"
      ]
    },
    {
      "content": "Age:",
      "children": [
        "18 - 65+"
      ]
    },
    {
      "content": "Placements:",
      "children": [
        "News Feed on mobile devices, News Feed on desktop computers or Right column on desktop computers"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Using the Graph Explorer API v2.7 (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) and a uri of:

act_FACEBOOK IDENTIFIER/targetingsentencelines?targeting_spec={%22geo_locations%22:{%22cities%22:[{%22key%22:%222431637%22,%22radius%22:%2210%22,%22distance_unit%22:%22mile%22}]},%22age_min%22:%2218%22,%22device_platforms%22:[%22mobile%22,%22desktop%22],%22publisher_platforms%22:[%22facebook%22],%22facebook_positions%22:[%22feed%22,%22right_hand_column%22]}

I get the same results as in staging, and development.

Comment: Tried adding: locale=en_US in the request and that didn't change it either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding local=en_US does work. I mis-typed it the first time.